# location based data prefetching

Tags: algorithm, localdatacache

I'm trying to develop a location based data prefetching algorithm. just reading about it, what it is and what need to be done. i need some good references to establish a solid foundation for my knowledge and start developing it. need you guys to help me to find good reference materials. thanx in advance.

Rangana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting article: http://suif.stanford.edu/papers/mowry92/tech.html

Maybe it helps...

Comment: thanx Tony it will help me very much... !